# Autocomplete disabled when using typescript union type checking

Tags: javascript, typescript, ide, typechecking

I'm trying to get the typescript autocomplete to work with a function like this :

```js
interface WeatherData {
  coord: { lon: number; lat: number };
}

const fetchWeatherData = async (
  location: string
): Promise<WeatherData | Error> => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `/weathr?q=${location}&APPID=${process.env.API_KEY}`
    );
    return res.data;
  } catch (e) {
    return new Error("Couldn't fetch weather data");
  }
};
```

It will return the data If network request is successful otherwise an error with a custom message.

But autocomplete is completely disabled this way and I can't access any fields I defined in `WeatherData` interface :

[image: autocomplete]

How can I use the autocomplete feature with typescript union type checking ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `WeatherData | Error` is not guaranteed to have any specific property, so you can't destructure it.

```
interface WeatherData {
  coord: { lon: number; lat: number };
}

// Use `declare` to just work with the type of this function.
declare function fetchWeatherData(): WeatherData | Error

async function go() {
  const { coord } = await fetchWeatherData()
}
```

This gives the type error:

> Property 'coord' does not exist on type 'WeatherData | Error'.(2339)

This is because `coord` is not a property that exists on `Error`, so if an object of type `Error` is returned, then you are accessing an invalid property.

[See PLayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOoTmAFtAIpuZAbwChlkEB7SqAEwC5jkAbSkRkAVwFsAjaANwtMHHvyjIAvgJKSSJAPQLkAVQDOKAAa0ICZnCgRNyMJWQArTmrDIA7jQDWd4NhM4TATwAOKSjDfAasgwnCAIYMBsAHQkOnoGKCFhEWzBEGAIWOiYOFD4YHAAFACUjNnYeATIAD7IAKJQUDTycGoeYcGh4ZEgyADmlCXEZBRs1kxUNLRSyAC8yHC2cC5pGVkYFXkEJbJAA)

---

The simple fix is narrow the type to make sure it's not an error before you access any non-error properties:

```
interface WeatherData {
  coord: { lon: number; lat: number };
}

// Use `declare` to just work with the type of this function.
declare function fetchWeatherData(): WeatherData | Error

async function go() {
  const result = await fetchWeatherData()
  if (result instanceof Error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch weather', result)
  } else {
    console.log('geo location', result.coord.lat, result.coord.lon) // fine
  }
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOoTmAFtAIpuZAbwChlkEB7SqAEwC5jkAbSkRkAVwFsAjaANwtMHHvyjIAvgJKSSJAPQLkAVQDOKAAa0ICZnCgRNyMJWQArTmrDIA7jQDWd4NhM4TATwAOKSjDfAasgwnCAIYMBsAHQkOnoGKCFhEWzBEGAIWOiYOFD4YHAAFACUjNnYeATIAD7IAKJQUDTycGoeYcGh4ZEgyADmlCXEZBRs1siGapzMNgC8yHC2cC5pGVkYFXkEJSPA-oWT0zag1nBhEH71jTTFw+TkVCBqlMwQUdBNUIUA5ABiy69aCYzDB0pk7Btct8ADQTCBTGbFEaSZAQZgaO73R7PV5RVh9H59C4sSgITA9GFwhFgKJUGi0PGYWGHGa06h0PFsW5KYKgCDI2RAA)

---

Although, perhaps what you meant to do was to `throw` an `Error`, which interrupts the normal control flow. This would allow you to *only* return a `WeatherData` since the code that handles the return value will be skipped if the error is raised.

```
interface WeatherData {
  coord: { lon: number; lat: number };
}

function fetchWeatherData(): WeatherData {
  if (Math.random() > 0.9) throw new Error('Failed to fetch weather')
  return { coord: { lat: 123, lon: 45 }}
}

async function go() {
  const { coord } = await fetchWeatherData() // fine
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOoTmAFtAIpuZAbwChlkEB7SqAEwC5jkAbSkRkAVwFsAjaANwtMHHvyjIAvgJKSSJGJxAIwwNshgQwCLOkw4o+MHAAUASkZ7seAsTLJgMZCYCy+gHRQ4IWpW7nkAD5kAAZ3AE4zZGwoSgB3ZBAIBIBRKFioEwByADE4YGYIWmjKDS0dZDiMaygss3soLU4oECYqGgYmZhFkAEYAJgBmABoWNkYAFgBWKTk5EjgAZwBPZQ0lFTVWgHNKANJyKhBFsDbqOilkAF5kODj8081tXWqDI1MogHpPjVAIWSAA)